# How can I browse the results of this code in JTextArea list?

Tags: java, list, swing, textarea

I have this code for searching duplicate files and I dont know how to show the results in a text area like a list.

```
public static void find(Map<String, List<String>> lists, File dir) {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            find(lists, f);
        } else {
                String hash = f.getName() + f.length();
                List<String> list = lists.get(hash);
                if (list == null) {

                    // Create a linked list and add duplicate entries
                    list = new LinkedList<String>();
                    lists.put(hash, list);
                }
                list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried so, but it did not work

logScrollPane.add(list1);
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

```
            Map<String, List<String>> lists = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            find(lists, file);

            //This is where a real application would open the file.
            listModel.addElement("Looking for Duplicates in Folder Name: " + file.getName() + " at location " + file.getParent());
            listModel.addElement("Double Click on File to open the Folder");

            for (List<String> list : lists.values()) {
               if (list.size() > 1) {
                   listModel.addElement("--");
                   listModel.addElement("Duplicates Found");
                   for (String file1 : list) {
                       listModel.addElement(file1);
                   }
               }
           }
           listModel.addElement("--");
```

Comment: Do you want to add the results into a `JTextArea` or in a `JList`? Because from the code you gave us, it looks like you use `JList`, but in title you write `JTextArea`.

Comment: First I want add results in JLIst,and after list in TextArea

Comment: *First I want add results in JLIst,and after list in TextArea* - why would you want it in two places. I'm not understanding the requirement. In any case if you have the data in the JList then you iterate throught the list to get each value and add it to a JTextArea using the append(...) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

This is a standalone demo that will show duplicates as either a `JList` or `JTextArea`. Take what you need.

I'm not sure where you were running into trouble, so take a look at the implementation of `doFind()` below to see two different sections, one populating the list and the other populating the text area.

Much of the rest of the code is just Swing stuff to make the standalone example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class ListDemo extends JFrame {

  DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
  JList list = new JList(listModel);
  JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
  JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
  JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
  JScrollPane textAreaScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
  JTextField pathTextField = new JTextField();
  JButton findButton = new JButton("Find");

  /**
   * Original implementation of "find" from question.
   * 
   * @param lists
   * @param dir 
   */
  public static void find(Map<String, List<String>> lists, File dir) {
    for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
      if (f.isDirectory()) {
        find(lists, f);
      } else {
        String hash = f.getName() + f.length();
        List<String> list = lists.get(hash);
        if (list == null) {

          // Create a linked listScrollPane and add duplicate entries
          list = new LinkedList<String>();
          lists.put(hash, list);
        }
        list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
      }
    }
  }

  public void doFind() {
    String path = pathTextField.getText();
    if (path == null || path.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }
    File file = new File(path);
    if (!(file.exists() && file.isDirectory())) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Not a valid path.");
      return;
    }

    Map<String, List<String>> lists = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Populate list model
    listModel.clear();
    find(lists, file);
    for (List<String> list : lists.values()) {
      if (list.size() > 1) {
        listModel.addElement("--");
        listModel.addElement("Duplicates Found");
        for (String file1 : list) {
          listModel.addElement(file1);
        }
      }
    }
    listModel.addElement("--");

    // Populate text area
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    find(lists, file);
    for (List<String> list : lists.values()) {
      if (list.size() > 1) {
        sb.append("--\n");
        sb.append("Duplicates Found\n");
        for (String file1 : list) {
          sb.append(file1);
          sb.append("\n");
        }
      }
    }
    sb.append("--\n");
    textArea.setText(sb.toString());   
  }

  public ListDemo() {
    setTitle("List Demo");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    centerPanel.add(listScrollPane);
    centerPanel.add(textAreaScrollPane);
    add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pathTextField.setColumns(30);
    buttonPanel.add(pathTextField);
    buttonPanel.add(findButton);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    findButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doFind();
      }
    });
  }

  public static final void main(String[] args) {
    // Run in GUI thread
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        ListDemo frame = new ListDemo();
        // Center in screen and show
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - frame.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - frame.getSize().height / 2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
  }
}
```

Note that this is not the best way of doing things, since the file search is done on the GUI thread and the results don't appear incrementally, but it will work in a pinch.